# How to override an invalid XSD property type in a SOAP response to allow parsing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap, service-reference

I am trying to consume a SOAP service using Visual Studio's "Add Service Reference" tool.

One of the types defined in the service WSDL has the following property:

```
<xsd:element name="paymentDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
```

However, when requesting data for which this property value is null, it will be returned in the raw XML as:

```
<paymentDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"/>
```

Which causes the following exception when the XML is deserialized: `FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.`

I cannot fix the bug in the SOAP service to change the XML response (which should have `xsd:nil` as the type if I am correct).

**What would be a good workaround so that it doesn't throw an exception and allows me to access the property value, at least as a string?**

Is there any way I could override the deserialization of the XML response? Changing the corresponding property type from `DateTime` to `string` in the `Reference.cs` file will not help (it seems the deserializer uses the type information present in the XML reponse).

If I remove the property from `Reference.cs` the exception will not be thrown, but then I don't have access to the property value which I need.

Comment: _"Changing the corresponding property type from DateTime to string in the Reference.cs file will not help"_  - barring the trouble this will cause when regenerating the proxy, it should work. What happens exactly when you do this, recompile and call the service?

Comment: @CodeCaster I get exactly the same exception :/, this is why I mentioned it didn't help. Only if I delete the property the exception goes away (along with the property value...)

Comment: Have you tried modifying your local copy of the WSDL?

Comment: No, but from my understanding the WSDL is correct (and any change to the WSDL could also be done to the proxy classes), only the XML response is incorrect (the xsi:type should be set to "xsd:nil").

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with the following workaround to inspect the raw XML response and modify it before it is parsed by WCF.

It basically replaces the incorrect `<paymentDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"></paymentDate>` with the expected `<paymentDate xsi:nil="true"></paymentDate>`.

```
public class MyRoutine {
    public static void Main() {
         var client = new MyServiceClient();
         client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new InspectorBehavior());
    }
}

public class InspectorBehavior : IEndpointBehavior {
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyMessageInspector());
    }
}

public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector {
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel) {
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) {
        reply = ChangeString(reply, from: "<paymentDate xsi:type=\"xsd:dateTime\"></paymentDate>", to: "<paymentDate xsi:nil=\"true\"></paymentDate>");
    }

    public static Message ChangeString(Message oldMessage, string from, string to) {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        oldMessage.WriteMessage(xw);
        xw.Flush();
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        xw.Close();

        body = body.Replace(from, to);

        ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
        var xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(xdr, int.MaxValue, oldMessage.Version);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(oldMessage.Properties);
        return newMessage;
    }
}
```